# Read JSON URL using Visual Basic .net

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I'm trying to read URL containing JSON
Reading the file in the URL is ok, but when trying to parse the JSON I get an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Additional information: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 2, position 2.
```

The code:

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest  
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing  
    Dim reader As StreamReader  

    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://phvarde.kundeside.dk/json?key=t6%$SVAKsG39"), HttpWebRequest)

    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

    Dim rawresp As String
    rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

    Dim jResults As Object = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
    TxtFornavn.Text = If(jResults("name") Is Nothing, "", jResults("name").ToString())
    TxtAdresse.Text = If(jResults("address") Is Nothing, "", jResults("address").ToString())
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON in Visual Basic .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905958/deserializing-json-in-visual-basic-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because your JSON represents an array of objects, not just a single object.  In this case you need to use `JArray.Parse` instead of `JObject.Parse`.

```
Dim array As JArray = JArray.Parse(json)

For Each item As JObject In array
    Dim name As String = If(item("name") Is Nothing, "", item("name").ToString())
    Dim address As String = If(item("address") Is Nothing, "", item("address").ToString())
    // ... process name and address ...
Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2wfA17

Comment: How can I implement you solution using an array??  The code: Dim jsonstr As String = File.ReadAllText("c:\temp\json.json")

            Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonstr)
            Dim results As Generic.List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList()

            For Each item As JProperty In results
                item.CreateReader()
                Select Case item.Name
                    Case "name"
                        TxtFornavn.Text = item.Value.ToString
                    End select

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  Can you edit your question to clarify?  Putting code in the comments section doesn't work very well.

Comment: I'm trying to get one record at a time and display it in a windowsform. When the first data has been approved we will send it to an SQL database and the NeXT record should load to the windowsform.

Comment: This sounds like a different issue.  I would recommend opening a new question.