# How to deserialize an array of values with a fixed schema to a strongly typed data class?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I am having some trouble figuring out a clean (as possible) way to deserialize some JSON data in a particular format.  I want to deserialize the data to strongly typed data object classes, pretty flexible regarding the specifics of this.  Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1473730993,
    "total_players": 945,
    "max_score": 8961474,
    "players": {
            "Player1Username": [
            121,
            "somestring",
            679900,
            5,
            4497,
            "anotherString",
            "thirdString",
            "fourthString",
            123,
            22,
            "YetAnotherString"],
        "Player2Username": [
            886,
            "stillAstring",
            1677,
            1,
            9876,
            "alwaysAstring",
            "thirdString",
            "fourthString",
            876,
            77,
            "string"]
        }
}
```

The specific parts I am unsure about are:

1. Would the collection of players be considered a dictionary?  The username could serve as the key, but the value is throwing me off since it would be a mixed collection of string and integer values.
2. A player is comprised entirely of unnamed values.  I have pretty much always worked with JSON data that had named properties and values (ex. timestamp, total_players, etc. at the very top)

Say I have a top level class like this:

```
public class ScoreboardResults
{
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public int total_players { get; set; }
    public int max_score { get; set; }
    public List<Player> players { get; set; }
}
```

What would the Player object look like given that it is basically a key/value with the username serving as the key, and the value being a collection of mixed integers and strings?  The data for each player element is always in the same order, so I know that the first value in the collection is their UniqueID, the second value is a player description, etc.  I would like the player class to be something like this:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int UniqueID { get; set; }
    public string PlayerDescription { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
    .... Following this pattern for all of the values in each player element
    ....
    ....
}
```

I am sure this is a pretty straightforward thing to do using JSON.NET, which is why I wanted to avoid any of the ideas I had on how to accomplish this.  What I came up with would have been un-elegant and probably error prone to some degree during the serialization process.

**EDIT**

Here are the classes that get generated when using the past as JSON classes as suggested by [snow_FFFFFF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3242103/snow-ffffff):

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public int total_players { get; set; }
    public int max_score { get; set; }
    public Players players { get; set; }
}

public class Players
{
    public object[] Player1Username { get; set; }
    public object[] Player2Username { get; set; }
}
```

What is not clear to me is how do I deserialize the JSON data in the "players" element as a List with Player1Username being a simple string property on the Player object.  As for the collection of intermixed strings and integers, I am confident I can get those into individual properties on the Player object without issue.

Comment: You should be able to use a converter like the one in [JSON deserialization - Map array indices to properties with JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757412/json-deserialization-map-array-indices-to-properties-with-json-net) for your `Player` class, then make `players` be a `Dictionary<string, Player>`.

Comment: Here's a generic converter that does just what you want: [Deserializing JSON in Visual Basic .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905958/deserializing-json-in-visual-basic-net).  But, it's in VB.NET...

Comment: [@dbc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc), I think that is what I am looking for.  This looks like it should do exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated your title to more clearly reflect the problem.  This question ends up being duplicated quite frequently but apparently isn't easy to find via search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The converter from [Deserializing JSON in Visual Basic .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905958/deserializing-json-in-visual-basic-net) should do what you need, suitably translated from VB.NET to c#:

```
public class ObjectToArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T) == objectType;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var objectType = value.GetType();
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("invalid type {0}.", objectType.FullName));
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var property in SerializableProperties(contract))
        {
            var propertyValue = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value);
            if (property.Converter != null && property.Converter.CanWrite)
                property.Converter.WriteJson(writer, propertyValue, serializer);
            else
                serializer.Serialize(writer, propertyValue);
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("invalid type {0}.", objectType.FullName));

        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("token {0} was not JsonToken.StartArray", reader.TokenType));

        // Not implemented: JsonObjectContract.CreatorParameters, serialization callbacks, 
        existingValue = existingValue ?? contract.DefaultCreator();

        using (var enumerator = SerializableProperties(contract).GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                switch (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.EndArray:
                        return existingValue;

                    default:
                        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {
                            reader.Skip();
                            break;
                        }
                        var property = enumerator.Current;
                        object propertyValue;
                        // TODO:
                        // https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm
                        // JsonProperty.ItemConverter, ItemIsReference, ItemReferenceLoopHandling, ItemTypeNameHandling, DefaultValue, DefaultValueHandling, ReferenceLoopHandling, Required, TypeNameHandling, ...
                        if (property.Converter != null && property.Converter.CanRead)
                            propertyValue = property.Converter.ReadJson(reader, property.PropertyType, property.ValueProvider.GetValue(existingValue), serializer);
                        else
                            propertyValue = serializer.Deserialize(reader, property.PropertyType);
                        property.ValueProvider.SetValue(existingValue, propertyValue);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<JsonProperty> SerializableProperties(JsonObjectContract contract)
    {
        return contract.Properties.Where(p => !p.Ignored && p.Readable && p.Writable);
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        return reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();
    }

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Next, add the converter to your `Player` class, and indicate the order of each property using [`JsonPropertyAttribute.Order`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_Order.htm):

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectToArrayConverter<Player>))]
public class Player
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public int UniqueID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public string PlayerDescription { get; set; }
    // Other fields as required.
}
```

Then finally, declare your root object as follows:

```
public class ScoreboardResults
{
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public int total_players { get; set; }
    public int max_score { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Player> players { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I have moved `Username` out of the `Player` class and into the dictionary, as a key.

Note that [data contract attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm) can be used instead of Newtonsoft attributes to specify order:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectToArrayConverter<Player>))]
[DataContract]
public class Player
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int UniqueID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string PlayerDescription { get; set; }
    // Other fields as required.
}
```

Demo fiddles [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ULduAc), [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mrF0Vu) and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/clNlC9).

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Couldn't have asked for a cleaner solution.  The fact that it is generic and reusable is awesome.  Thanks for a great solution!

Comment: Unfortunately the converter is not recursive.

Comment: It doesn't work when properties have JsonConverterAttribute. How can I Serialize and Deserialize with JsonConverter?

Comment: @wishmaster35 - answer updated, however in the future you really should ask another question **with a new [mcve] that demonstrates your problem** since the existing answer meet the needs of this question.

Answer (score 5):

A good way to get started would be to let visual studio generate your class based on the JSON.  Open a blank class file and go to EDIT -> PASTE SPECIAL -> PASTE JSON As CLASSES.

This will generate a file with the necessary class(es) to serialize/deserialize your JSON.

Comment: How I never knew about this feature is beyond me.  I had always used json2csharp, which is similar but it is great to have that functionality directly in VS.

When I do that for my example data in the OP, it generates a Players class with two properties of the type object[].  They are named Player1Username, and Player2Username.  Is there a way to get the value "Player1Username" and set it to a string Username property on a Player object containing the array of the other values associated with each player?

Comment: I think they are type object[] because you just have a bunch of random values as opposed to normal name/value pairs that you would expect in JSON.  It sounds like you don't have control over the json, so I guess you can't change it.  However, you essentially have an array of values of different types, so it seems like object[] is the best you can do.  Maybe just add some other readonly properties for parsing the object[].

Comment: Yep, and that is presenting the problem for me.  I will make an edit to the OP so I can format the code and hopefully explain the issue more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create a class like below

Note : you can use Paste Special option in visual studio to generate all the classes related to the JSON

Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json As Classes

it will create all the classes related to the JSON

Note : refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607277/how-to-parse-an-example-string-in-c-sharp/38608187#38608187) I have already answer similar like this..

Comment: This has already been posted.  It also does not solve the actual problem.  It is generating a strongly typed property for each player (username) in the players collection.  I am trying to make it use a single generic Player object with the username being a property within it.

Comment: Also see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405559/c-sharp-looping-array-object-multidimensional-from-ajax-post/44406004#44406004