# Deserialize JSON Array of Property Values Into Object Without Index Names

Tags: c#, arrays, json, web-services, deserialization

I am getting response from the following public API, which contains flight information (contains 12 fields each). I am trying deserialize this response into my object structure using Newtonsoft.JSON. I don't really need to use this package - also recommendations are welcome.

[The API response that contains the flight data (WARNING, it's kinda a big response)](https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all)

The parsed response looks something like following:

```
{
"time": 1484343110,
"states": [
[
  "a25f32",
  "N252CV  ",
  "United States",
  1484343109,
  1484343109,
  -86.9989,
  40.5451,
  2209.8,
  false,
  95.05,
  327.6,
  4.55,
  null
],
[
  "aac8a4",
  "UAL35   ",
  "United States",
  1484343108,
  1484343108,
  -128.0702,
  43.3022,
  9144,
  false,
  220.81,
  323.72,
  0,
  null
]]
}
```

First problem: The root element contains two values, which are "time" and "states" which is an array of flight information. Therefore, I tried to create my class structures like following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Field information is taken from
/// https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html
/// </summary>
public class FlightInformation
{
    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("states")]
    public List<FlightDetail> FlightDetails { get; set; }
}


public class FlightDetail
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "icao24")]
    public string ICAOAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "callsign")]
    public string AircraftCallsign { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "country")]
    public string OriginCountry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "time_position")]
    public string LastPositionUpdate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "time_velocity")]
    public string LastVelocityUpdate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "longitude")]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "latitude")]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "altitude")]
    public string Altitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "on_ground")]
    public string IsOnGround { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "velocity")]
    public string Velocity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "heading")]
    public string Heading { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "vertical_rate")]
    public string VerticalRate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sensors")]
    public string[] Sensors { get; set; }
}
```

Second problem: the objects inside the "states" array does not contain field names. But just because their documentation gave the names of the fields, I've put them in the `JsonProperty` anyway.

The way I am doing is like this (in my main app):

```
var apiResponse = _rest.GetResponse("https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all");

//first thing I tried
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, FlightInformation>>(apiResponse);

//second thing I tried
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlightInformation>(apiResponse);

//third thing
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlightInformation>(apiResponse).FlightDetails;

//and fourth thing...
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FlightDetail>>(apiResponse);
```

At every one of them, the error I am getting is quite different. The result with the dictionary is like this:

> Error converting value 1484344840 to type 'FlightManager.DAL.FlightInformation'.

The result with the second one:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'FlightManager.DAL.FlightDetail' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

The result with the third one is same as second one.

The result with the last (fourth) one is:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FlightManager.DAL.FlightDetail]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

As I said, I don't really need to use Newtonsoft.JSON as I am only experimenting... What could I be doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [C# JSON.NET - Deserialize response that uses an unusual data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39462464/3744182).  Does that question answer yours?