# JSON.NET parse to type based on parent

Tags: json.net

I get a whole bunch of "settings" from an API via JSON which looks like this:

```
{
    ...
    "SettingA": { "value": [
        [ 3200, 0  ], 
        [ 4300, 0  ], 
        [ 5600, 0  ], 
        [ 7000, 0  ]
    ], "type": "array", "readonly": 1},
    "SettingB": { "value": [
        [ 3, 3320, -0.6, "Auto WB"  ], 
        [ 7, 3200, 0, "Tungsten"  ], 
        [ 7, 4300, 0, "Fluorescent"  ], 
        [ 7, 5600, 0, "Daylight"  ], 
        [ 7, 7000, 0, "Daylight cool"  ]
    ], "type": "array", "readonly": 1}
    ...
}
```

Based on the keyword like "SettingA" or "SettingB", I need to serialize it's VALUE property to a specific type (*if* known, some settings can stay as JTOKEN or JARRAY, as I don't care)

Is there an elgant way of deserializing the VALUE to a corresponding type? Especially, because the properties are NOT NAMED, so I would have to assign properties by index.

Currently, I am doing this (which works, but requires lots of hand-writing):

```
foreach (JToken item in table)
{
    var p = new WhiteBalancePreset(item.Value<int>(0), item.Value<double>(1),
        item.Value<double>(2), item.Value<string>(3));
    if (p.State != 0)
        presets.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: Is `"value"` always an array?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can use a non-generic version of `ObjectToArrayConverter<T>` from *[How to deserialize objects containing arrays of values with a fixed schema to strongly typed data classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39461518/3744182)* to serialize your `SettingA` and `SettingB` types from and to arrays of property values.  The easiest way to do it is to define a base class for all such settings with the converter applied directly:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectToArrayConverter))]
public abstract class SettingBase
{
}

public class ObjectToArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static bool ShouldSkip(JsonProperty property)
    {
        return property.Ignored || !property.Readable || !property.Writable;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var type = value.GetType();
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(type) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("invalid type " + type.FullName);
        var list = contract.Properties.Where(p => !ShouldSkip(p)).Select(p => p.ValueProvider.GetValue(value));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type != JTokenType.Array)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("token was not an array");
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType) as JsonObjectContract;
        if (contract == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("invalid type " + objectType.FullName);
        var value = existingValue ?? contract.DefaultCreator();
        foreach (var pair in contract.Properties.Where(p => !ShouldSkip(p)).Zip(token, (p, v) => new { Value = v, Property = p }))
        {
            var propertyValue = pair.Value.ToObject(pair.Property.PropertyType, serializer);
            pair.Property.ValueProvider.SetValue(value, propertyValue);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then define `SettingA` and `SettingB` as derived types:

```
public class SettingA : SettingBase
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public double Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class SettingB : SettingBase
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public double ColorTemperature { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public double GammaCorrection { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

They will now be serialized from and to JSON as arrays of property values rather than objects.  Note that all properties must be marked with [`[JsonProperty(Order = XXX)]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm) to be serialized reliably with this converter.  [`[DataContract]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) and [`[DataMember(Order = XXX)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx) could be used instead as those are also [supported by Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm).

The next stage, correctly deserializing the named JSON properties `"SettingA"` and `"SettingB"`, can be handled by using generics as well. define the following types:

```
public class SettingsTable<TSettings> where TSettings : SettingBase
{
    public SettingsTable() { this.Value = new List<TSettings>(); }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<TSettings> Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("readonly")]
    public int Readonly { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsSet
{
    public SettingsSet() { this.OtherSettings = new Dictionary<string, JToken>(); }

    public SettingsTable<SettingA> SettingA { get; set; }

    public SettingsTable<SettingB> SettingB { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> OtherSettings { get; set; }
}
```

The root type `SettingsSet` contains defined properties for the settings you are interested in, namely `SettingA` and `SettingB`.  Unknown or uninteresting settings are captured by `OtherSettings` which is marked with [`[JsonExtensionData]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm).

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SvT9TN).