# convert list object to json in c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have an object model that looks like this:

```
public class Myclass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

public ContentResult GetList(List<Myclass> model)
{

    var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        model,
        Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });

    return Content(list, "application/json");
}
```

I need OUTPUT:

```
[[1,"name1",23],[2,"name2",30],[3,"name3",26],[4,"name4",29]]
```

Comment: you need to provide better detail of what you are currently getting...the JSON you showed in your desired output is not valid JSON, and from your code it is likely you are actually getting correct JSON

Comment: I should clarify - when I say it is not valid JSON I mean it does not represent JSON that is bound to any kind of object structure.

Comment: FYI if you don't need any special settings like `ReferenceLoopHandling` (which it looks like you don't), you can `return Json(model);` and not bother with explicit serialization (just return `JsonResult` instead of `ContentResult`)

Comment: Your output shows an array of arrays, not an array of objects.

Comment: this method return [{"Id":1,"name1",23},{"Id":2,"name2",30},{"Id":3,"name3",26},{"Id":4,"name4",29},]

Comment: i need return value without attribute name like this  [{1,"name1",23},{2,"name2",30},{3,"name3",26},{4,"name4",29}]

Comment: that's because the method is returning proper JSON?  you want an array of arrays where the arrays are of inconsistent types (string and ints)?  you'll probably have to manually generate those strings because there isn't a serializer in the world that will generate that kind of output

Comment: @MohamedAbdullah https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp What you are asking for is not JSON

Comment: In your two comments you are NOT writing valid json.

Comment: sorry this method return [{"Id":1,"name":"name1","age":23},{"Id":2,"name":"name2",""age":30},{"Id":3,"name":"name3","age":26}‌​,{"Id":4,"name":"name4","age":29}‌​]

Comment: If what you really want is an array of arrays then convert your list to that type before serialization: `model.Select(m => new object[] { m.Id, m.name, m.age });`

Comment: @RobertPetz *there isn't a serializer in the world that will generate that kind of output* - Sure? [Computer says no](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XKW2TP)

Comment: @FedericoDipuma  Thank you for your assistance  . ... solved

Comment: You could use `ObjectToArrayConverter<Myclass>` from [C# JSON.NET - Deserialize response that uses an unusual data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462464/3744182).

Answer (score -2):

you can use this workaround if it satisfy your needs, please let me know if this works

```
        List<Myclass> model = new List<Myclass>();
        model.Add(new Myclass() { Id = 1, Name = "Name1", Age = 50 });
        model.Add(new Myclass() { Id = 2, Name = "Name2", Age = 51 });
        model.Add(new Myclass() { Id = 3, Name = "Name3", Age = 52 });

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        //If you want to replace { with [ and } with ]
        json = json.Replace("{", "[").Replace("}", "]");

        //you can use this workaround to get rid of property names
        string propHeader = "\"{0}\":";

        json= json.Replace(string.Format(propHeader, "Id"), "")
            .Replace(string.Format(propHeader, "Name"),"")
            .Replace(string.Format(propHeader, "Age"), "");

        Console.WriteLine(json);
```