# Any way to deserialize a JSON array to object with fields using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I want to deserialize a JSON array using Newtonsoft to class.

The JSON array like (Api returns that)

```
[1,"1",true,2,3]
```

To class

```
class MyObject {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public bool IsIt { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way except creating the constructor like

```
public MyObject(object[] array) {
    Number = (int)array[0];
    Data = (string)array[1];
    IsIt = (bool)array[2];
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to change the API if you can.

Comment: In short - no, API is terrible, if it returns such array of objects

Comment: I know that API is terrible, but I need to work with it.

Comment: It's not a bad API, just use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and read about dynamic objects.

Comment: You could use `ObjectToArrayConverter<MyObject>` from [C# JSON.NET - Deserialize response that uses an unusual data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462464/3744182).

Comment: Thanks @dbc that's what I needed