# Deserialize json array of array to List of string in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to know how can I convert(Deserialize) **a json array of json array** to a **list of string**.

which means that inner array should be converted into string

the json is :

```
[
      [
         "a",
         "b",
         "c",
         null,
         1
      ],
      [
         "d",
         "e",
         null,
         2
      ]
]
```

the c# code using built-in c# json deserializer is :

```
List<string> myList = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(json);
```

This exception occurs :

[image]

And Newtonsoft :

```
List<string> myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
```

[image]

After I couldn't deserialize [this json](https://pastebin.pl/view/d51fa669) (which is google translate api response) with built-in deserializer in dotnetcore 3.1 and Newtonsoft , I decided to convert it manually to classes and strings but my code didn't work.

the result should be like that :

list :

item 1 :

```
[
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        null,
        1
]
```

item 2 :

```
[
        "d",
        "e",
        null,
        2
]
```

1. Is there a way to deserialize the json I mentioned in the link into classes ? (Visual Studio Special Paste didn't work)
2. Why I cannot convert json array of json array into List of string ?
3. Is this problem related with [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31007) ?

Comment: `d,` in json looks like a syntax error. `1` and `2` looks like `int` but not `string`.

Comment: Deserialize it into a nested collections (an array of string arrays, or something similar), and then walk through the results, adding each string to a list you create

Comment: @aepot I checked that out , putting d in " " the problem is not d .

Comment: Also you have array of arrays here, not array of `string`.

Comment: How should resulting string look?

Comment: @GuruStron I added what result string should look like

Comment: @Parsa see the `List<JArray>` version in my answer. You can use `Formatting.Indented` to get multiline strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not only string in your collection and you have nested arrays, so `List<string>` does not represent your JSON structure. If you want to get only string you can do something like this (this one is with Newtonsoft, after fixing the `d` value):

```
var strings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(json)
    .Select(arr => arr.OfType<string>().ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Or using `arr => arr.Select(a => a?.ToString()` in `Select` if you want to convert all values to strings.

Or you can convert to `List<JArray>` with Newtonsoft and call `ToString` on it:

```
List<string> strings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JArray>>(json)
    .Select(jarr => jarr.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None)) 
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strings)); // prints "["a","b","c",null,1], ["d","e",null,2]"
```

Comment: your code works perfectly ! , thank you , do you know how can I make a c# class model for the json I provided in that link ? the visual studio couldn't do that. online sites couldn't too.

Comment: @Parsa I'm afraid only something similar to `List<List<object>>` or `List<JArray>` or `List<JToken>` or just `JToken` with next manual handling. TBH it looks like somebody used arrays in few places where JSON object should be.