# Deserializing Json array of array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I'm trying to Deserialize an array of array in c# but I keep getting errors
here's the Json response

```json
{
   "result":{
      "14400":[
         [
            1664006400,
            19121.92,
            19189,
            18925.94,
            18997.14,
            40878.7735,
            780289470.6555521
         ],
         [
            1664020800,
            18996.63,
            19002.18,
            18988.8,
            18997.46,
            153.341,
            2912907.7335217
         ]
      ],
      "180":[
         [
            1664006400,
            18998.8,
            19000.05,
            18990.05,
            18997.14,
            319.25744,
            6064375.6882797
         ],
         [
            1664006580,
            18996.63,
            19002.18,
            18988.8,
            18997.46,
            153.341,
            2912907.7335217
         ]
      ],
      "1800":[
         [
            1664006400,
            19003.15,
            19025.07,
            18968.11,
            18997.14,
            4823.42007,
            91655099.2502063
         ],
         [
            1664008200,
            18996.63,
            19002.18,
            18988.8,
            18997.46,
            153.341,
            2912907.7335217
         ]
      ],
      "21600":[
         [
            1664020800,
            19136.9,
            19164.25,
            18925.94,
            18997.46,
            20740.99979,
            394973767.0314926
         ]
      ],
      "300":[
         [
            1664006400,
            18984.59,
            19001.1,
            18980.28,
            18997.14,
            591.96318,
            11243452.571249
         ],
         [
            1664006700,
            18996.63,
            19002.18,
            18988.8,
            18997.46,
            153.341,
            2912907.7335217
         ]
      ],
      "3600":[
         [
            1664006400,
            19078.19,
            19084.27,
            18925.94,
            18997.14,
            11653.39145,
            221429662.3864255
         ],
         [
            1664010000,
            18996.63,
            19002.18,
            18988.8,
            18997.46,
            153.341,
            2912907.7335217
         ]
      ],
      "60":[
         [
            1664006400,
            18995.8,
            18999.1,
            18993.77,
            18997.14,
            106.13386,
            2016106.7154772
         ],
         [
            1664006460,
            18996.63,
            19002.18,
            18988.8,
            18997.46,
            153.341,
            2912907.7335217
         ]
      ],
      "7200":[
         [
            1664006400,
            19136.9,
            19164.25,
            18925.94,
            18997.14,
            20587.65879,
            392060859.2979709
         ],
         [
            1664013600,
            18996.63,
            19002.18,
            18988.8,
            18997.46,
            153.341,
            2912907.7335217
         ]
      ],
      "900":[
         [
            1664006400,
            19008.41,
            19017.63,
            18968.11,
            18997.14,
            2341.42806,
            44481574.1022888
         ],
         [
            1664007300,
            18996.63,
            19002.18,
            18988.8,
            18997.46,
            153.341,
            2912907.7335217
         ]
      ]
   },
   "allowance":{
      "cost":0,
      "remaining":10,
      "remainingPaid":9999999999,
      "account":"00000"
   }
}
```

I tried creating class for each array inside the result
EX:

```
  public class Rootobject
    {
        public Result result { get; set; }
        public Allowance allowance { get; set; }
    }


    public class R_14400
    {
        [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
        public long CloseTime { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
        public decimal Open { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
        public decimal High { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
        public decimal Low { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]
        public decimal Close { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 6)]
        public decimal Volume { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 7)]
        public decimal QuoteVolume { get; set; }
    }

    public class R_60
    {
        [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
        public long CloseTime { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
        public decimal Open { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
        public decimal High { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
        public decimal Low { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]
        public decimal Close { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 6)]
        public decimal Volume { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 7)]
        public decimal QuoteVolume { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public R_14400 _14400 { get; set; }
        //public float[][] _180 { get; set; }
        //public float[][] _1800 { get; set; }
        //public float[][] _21600 { get; set; }
        //public float[][] _300 { get; set; }
        //public float[][] _3600 { get; set; }
        public R_60 _60 { get; set; }
        //public float[][] _7200 { get; set; }
        //public float[][] _900 { get; set; }

    }



    public class Allowance
    {
        public int cost { get; set; }
        public int remaining { get; set; }
        public long remainingPaid { get; set; }
        public string account { get; set; }
    }
```

and then tried to do the following

```
        public class ObjectToArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462464/3744182
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(T) == objectType;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var objectType = value.GetType();
            var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType) as JsonObjectContract;
            if (contract == null)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("invalid type {0}.", objectType.FullName));
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var property in SerializableProperties(contract))
            {
                var propertyValue = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value);
                if (property.Converter != null && property.Converter.CanWrite)
                    property.Converter.WriteJson(writer, propertyValue, serializer);
                else
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, propertyValue);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType) as JsonObjectContract;
            if (contract == null)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("invalid type {0}.", objectType.FullName));

            if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                return null;
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("token {0} was not JsonToken.StartArray", reader.TokenType));

            // Not implemented: JsonObjectContract.CreatorParameters, serialization callbacks, 
            existingValue = existingValue ?? contract.DefaultCreator();

            using (var enumerator = SerializableProperties(contract).GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    switch (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
                    {
                        case JsonToken.EndArray:
                            return existingValue;

                        default:
                            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                            {
                                reader.Skip();
                                break;
                            }
                            var property = enumerator.Current;
                            object propertyValue;
                            // TODO:
                            // https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm
                            // JsonProperty.ItemConverter, ItemIsReference, ItemReferenceLoopHandling, ItemTypeNameHandling, DefaultValue, DefaultValueHandling, ReferenceLoopHandling, Required, TypeNameHandling, ...
                            if (property.Converter != null && property.Converter.CanRead)
                                propertyValue = property.Converter.ReadJson(reader, property.PropertyType, property.ValueProvider.GetValue(existingValue), serializer);
                            else
                                propertyValue = serializer.Deserialize(reader, property.PropertyType);
                            property.ValueProvider.SetValue(existingValue, propertyValue);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<JsonProperty> SerializableProperties(JsonObjectContract contract)
        {
            return contract.Properties.Where(p => !p.Ignored && p.Readable && p.Writable);
        }
    }
```

and then Deserializing

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new ObjectToArrayConverter<R_60>() },
};
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<R_60>>(JsonStr,settings);
```

I tried going through the Rootobject and then I tried using IList<IList> but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i saved your json in a file, then copied it and pasted it in Visual Studio as class:
[image]

And Visual Studio created slightly different model from what you posted. But property names were ugly, like `14400` so i overcame it with adding attribute specifying name of JSON prop:

```
[JsonProperty("14400")]
public float[][] CloseTime { get; set; }
```

So I ended up with such classes (it's up to you to add correct maping in attributes, but for me that worked):

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }

    public Allowance allowance { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("14400")]
    public float[][] CloseTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("180")]
    public float[][] Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("1800")]
    public float[][] High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("21600")]
    public float[][] Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("300")]
    public float[][] Close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3600")]
    public float[][] Volume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("60")]
    public float[][] QuoteVolume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("7200")]
    public float[][] _7200 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("900")]
    public float[][] _900 { get; set; }
}

public class Allowance
{
    public int cost { get; set; }

    public int remaining { get; set; }

    public long remainingPaid { get; set; }

    public string account { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for something different. For example his/her `R_14400` class represents an array item under the `result.14400` field. As far as I understand the question :)

Comment: with slight changes I made it work with this answer thank you Michal, you were a big help to me :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Brian Rogers' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558161/13268855) to map a Json array items to a particular object's properties.

With that Attribute and Converter in your hand, you can define your model classes like these:

```
class Root
{
    public Dictionary<int, InnerMost[]> Result { get; set; }
    public Allowance Allowance { get; set; }
}

class Allowance
{
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public int Remaining { get; set; }
    public long RemainingPaid { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(ArrayToObjectConverter<InnerMost>))] 
class InnerMost
{
    [JsonArrayIndex(0)]
    public long CloseTime { get; set; }
    [JsonArrayIndex(1)]
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    [JsonArrayIndex(2)]
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    [JsonArrayIndex(3)]
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    [JsonArrayIndex(4)]
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    [JsonArrayIndex(5)]
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }
    [JsonArrayIndex(6)]
    public decimal QuoteVolume { get; set; }
}
```

and the usage will be this simple:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

Here you can find a working version: [dotnet fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nph0Pw).

Comment: Thank you for the answer it didn't work it kept giving me an error "The given key was not present in the dictionary." I'm sure it's something wrong I did but your answer helped me in another place in the code so thank you very much

Comment: @Kha1ed I've tried my code with your example json and it worked fine. It is strange that it does not work on your side. I could put together a dotnetfiddle if you wish.

Comment: if it's not much work for you I'll be thankful to see an example in dotnetfiddle, thank you again

Comment: @Kha1ed I've updated my post with a dotnetfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this and then use the Newtonsoft.Json to deserialise it:

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
... 

Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
public class Allowance
{
    public int cost { get; set; }
    public int remaining { get; set; }
    public long remainingPaid { get; set; }
    public string account { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<List<double>> _14400 { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> _180 { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> _1800 { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> _21600 { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> _300 { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> _3600 { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> _60 { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> _7200 { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> _900 { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public Allowance allowance { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I kept getting the general error object reference not set to an instance
But thank you for the effort I might have done  something wrong