# Newtonsoft.Json serialize using property value as root name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have to serialize a list of objects in Json in C#, I'm using Newtonsoft.Json
I need to use the name value of the objects as the root name, like this:

```
"employees"  :
  {
    "John" :
      {
        "id" : 18,
        "email" : "john@email.com"
       },
    "Jack" :
       {
         "id" : 21,
         "email" : "jack@email.com"
        }
   }
```

Where John and Jack are the values of the name property for my employees

Comment: Can you explain why you need that kind of structure to represent something that can be an array of employees with a name property ?

Comment: These are the specifications that I have

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# JSON.NET - Deserialize response that uses an unusual data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461518/c-sharp-json-net-deserialize-response-that-uses-an-unusual-data-structure)

Comment: can't you challenge the specs? Makes much more sense as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but quick
You can use dictionary before serialization like this

```
class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var l = new[]
        {
            new Employee {Id = 1, Name = "1", Email = "1"},
            new Employee {Id = 2, Name = "2", Email = "2"}, 
            new Employee {Id = 2, Name = "3", Email = "3"}
        };

        var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { employees = l.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x) });
    }


    class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"employees":{"1":{"Id":1,"Email":"1"},"2":{"Id":2,"Email":"2"},"3":{"Id":2,"Email":"3"}}}
```

You can find more information here https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm I think you can solve this in more elegant way  using JsonConverterAttribute but it can be not easy