# How to return a Json from a list in an api without the properties names in netcore

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

for some legacy code, I need to return a list of rows than come from a list of the element, but, the client needs it without the property name.

This is what I need. (I know that inside this JSON return, it's an array list then it's not a valid JSON, but is the way that needs to be received by the front end I don't know why

```
{ "success":true,"msg":"","draw":"1","recordsTotal":14,"recordsFiltered":14,
{ "data": 
[
["Xiaomi","Redmi 8","10","6.0.1","","sadsadasd"],
["Xiaomi","Redmi 8","10","6.0.1","","sadsadasd"],
]
 }
```

This is what I got now

```
{"success":true,"msg":"","draw":"1","recordsTotal":14,"recordsFiltered":14,
  "data" :[
    {"Brand":"Xiaomi","Model":"Redmi 8","Version":10,"App":"4.3.3","Phone":"","AsignedUSer":"ceererer"},
    {"Brand":"Xiaomi","Model":"Redmi 8","Version":10,"App":"4.3.3","Phone":"","AsignedUSer":"ceererer"},
     ]
    }
```

And this is the code how I am retrieving the data

```
 return new JsonResult(new { success = true, msg = "",  draw ="1", recordsTotal = listToReturn.Count(),  recordsFiltered = listToReturn.Count() , 
   data =   listToReturn , 
            });
```

Comment: In your example above, the `What I need` json isn't valid.

Comment: Similar question/answer here, which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55199135/serialize-to-json-without-property-names

Comment: ok @Codexer, it's an invalid json, but its the returned expected data type from the client, an array of strings inside a json file,  the answer given by crowcoder work for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could project your list into arrays to extract the property values:

```
var data = listToReturn
.Select(d => new string[]{d.Brand, d.Model, d.Version, etc..})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didnt think on create and array of the element, jejej,

Answer (score 0):

Note that a "JSON" content without the property names will be a not valid JSON document.
What you need seems to be more like a CSV-like response.
Have you tried to format the result as CSV?

Comment: JSON arrays do not need objects with property names

Comment: Yes, I understand what you said, but on the client, the consumer of the API needs it that way, I don't know why really jejeje, in my case I'm only working on the backend part.

I will take a look at what you said, just in case I have a future similar work where I need to work on the front.

Comment: I see, yeah, as a good practice, I don't think the backend should concern about it, in case of more than 1 client consumes this backend that could be a problem, right? I mean, perhaps the client should treat that data returned as JSON, just removing the prop names.