# VB.NET syntax for Newtonsoft JsonProperty order property

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am trying to set the order in which various JSON properties get serialised, and all the examples I can find are using C#, and are like:

```
[JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
```

but I cannot find a way to write this in VB.NET which Visual Studio will accept - the obvious:

```
&lt;JsonProperty(Order = 1)&gt;
```

gives errors and won't compile .... (no doubt there's a way to format that last line,  but...)

As I also need to set the property name for the same property, e.g.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CardCode")]
```

in c#, how can I set both the name and order in vb.net using `JsonPropertyAttribute`?

Comment: Do `<JsonProperty(Order := 1)> Public Property MyProperty as MyType`.  You can see an example at [Deserializing JSON in Visual Basic .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31908231/3744182) and the linked fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Sw9Sw.  If you need more help, can you share your current code?

Comment: Thank you - that at least compiles! Whether r not it does the job or notw e shall see in due course...  :)   As the properties in this class also requrie another jsonproperty (name, to link them to the .NET data classes I (de)serialise to/from, it's interesting that to use both I need to use a line continuation character eg: 
   <JsonProperty(Order:=0)>_
   <JsonProperty("CardCode")>
   Public Property CardCode As String 
though putting them on the same line doesn't work!  Oh well...

Comment: Oh no - spoke too soon!  VS shows no syntax errors until trying to compile, then it doesn;t like the continuation character unless it is preceded by a space (fair enough) but then putting one in creates a syntax error with the next line (with the second jsonproperty.....  aargh!

Comment: So they go together, k so:
<JsonProperty(PropertyName:="CardCode", Order:=1)>

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  You can only have one `JsonProperty` attribute per property, but it can have many values set.

Comment: Yes - thanks again.  And not only did it compile, but ti dd the job too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for applying attributes with parameters in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) is described in [Attributes overview (Visual Basic): Attribute Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-parameters):

> **Attribute Parameters**
>
> Many attributes have parameters, which can be positional, unnamed, or named. Any positional parameters must be specified in a certain order and cannot be omitted; named parameters are optional and can be specified in any order. Positional parameters are specified first. For example, these three attributes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> <DllImport("user32.dll")>  
> <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=False, ExactSpelling:=False)>  
> <DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=False, SetLastError:=False)>
> ```

Thus, if you want to apply [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) to a property and set both the name and order, you must do:

```
Public Class Card
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="CardName", Order:=2)>
    Public Property Name As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="CardDescription", Order:=3, _
            NullValueHandling := NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling := DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate)>
    <System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")>
    Public Property Description As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="CardCode", Order:=1)>
    Public Property Code As String
End Class
```

Notes:

- As shown by the setting [`AllowMultiple = false`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.allowmultiple.aspx) in the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonPropertyAttribute.cs), only one instance of `JsonPropertyAttribute` can be applied to a given member or parameter:

  ```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
  public sealed class JsonPropertyAttribute : Attribute
  {
       // Contents of the type omitted
  }
  ```

  Thus all necessary `JsonPropertyAttribute` settings must be initialized in that one attribute.
- The line continuation character [`_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code) can be used to break attribute settings across multiple lines.  Attributes can be applied on the line(s) immediately preceding a property, however, so it is not necessary to use it in this case.
- According to the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) a JSON object is an *unordered set of name/value pairs*, so it is often not necessary to specify the order.

Sample VB.NET fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/469O09).